# Is setting the custom class in IB not working in Xcode 4.5?

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4.5

I have a button class named `BFToggleButton`, derived from `UIButton`. In my xib file, I dragged a  `UIButton`, changed its custom class as `BFToggleButton`. In the Objects part of the IB, I'm seeing this button as `Toggle Button - Button`.

However, in the code, when I call a method that's not present in `UIButton`, but present in `BFToggleButton` class, I get an exception saying that an unrecognized selector is sent to an instance of `UIButton`.

So that gives me the impression that there may be a problem about setting the custom class in Xcode 4.5. Because if I'm not missing anything this should work according to my experiences with the previous XCodes.

Have you experienced the same thing?

Comment: @charshep oh, yours is really interesting :S Tell us if you can get an improvement on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the problem was about the **Target Membership** of the `BFToggleButton` class. I right clicked on this class and selected Show File Inspector and saw that the Target Membership checkbox was not checked and that was why the interface builder didn't recognize this class.